# jQuery menu slide right

Tags: jquery, menu, slide

I'm doing a simple menu into a list with inside every single item a second menu.

`ul.first li` and `ul.second li`

The menu will slide on right becouse is a menu on the left side of the website.

I wrote this on jQuery:

```
var secs1 = $('ul.first > li');

secs1.hover(

    function () {
        $(this).find('ul.second').animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('ul.second').animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 250);
    }

);
```

It works perfect but there is a problem inside!

If I do mouse enter and mouse out on the single element it open and close many times as I did it.

This is the first think that I want to fix!

The second is:

if i mouse enter and mouse out before the toggle is completed I would like that it doesn't finish to toggle everything but stop to do that and start to toggle back to the origin.

I hope everything is clear enough for your help!

Thanks!

EDIT:

See it on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReuLr/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code. Tested, tidy and working. Enjoy!

http://jsfiddle.net/ReuLr/6/

Comment: Glad it works for you. It's also a more flexible solution if you have multiple sub-menues. Enjoy! :-)

Comment: There is only one more issue, maybe you can help me to fix it as well... when I mouseover and mouseout very fast I would like that it starts going back without finishing to go ahead... if you see your fiddle it complete the function to go on the right before closing... I would like it stops and going back... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.  For the paramaters passed in, the first `true` clears the animation queue, and the second `false` stops wherever you are in the animation before continuing instead of jumping to the animation's end:

```
var secs1 = $('ul.first > li');

secs1.hover(

    function () {
        $(this).find('ul.second').stop(true, false).animate({width:'toggle'}, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('ul.second').stop(true, false).animate({width:'toggle'}, 250);
    }

);
```

Comment: after 3 attempts it doesn't work anymore... seems that it mantain the width when I stop and than it re open it at half width...

Comment: You'll have to specify widths instead of using `toggle` then

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the hoverIntent plugin for JQuery. Check this demo: http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/

Comment: This is overkill, all that is necessary is to .stop() before .animate() - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a **.stop()** before **.animate()** and it will prevent queuing of animations.

```
$('ul.first > li').find('ul.second').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 500);
    },function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 250);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hey Toro, try my ammended code. If it doesn't work I am happy to take a look at this for you - why don't you throw some code up on jsFiddle.net and I'll take a look. :-)